# Hidden code cells (Jupyter lab) show up on github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Lab allows the user to hide a code cell, hide an output cell, or both. This is a very nice feature that is saved when saving the notebook, so it remembers to hide the cells when re-opening the notebooks.

When such notebooks are uploaded on Github, and the notebook is viewed on Github, the hidden cells are not anymore hidden.

Is there a workaround or do we have to wait for the Github wizards to implement this feature?

Comment: Have you sent a [magic letter](https://support.github.com/contact/feedback) to the GitHub wizards so they can start their wizardry?

Comment: Good suggestion. Might as well get it on their radar. But just realized that nbviewer.org doesn't hide the hidden cells either, so maybe start there.

Comment: I started a discussion on Jupyter Discourse, which received some insightful replies. The feature is under development and no common api has been adopted as of yet: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/hidden-cells-are-not-hidden-in-nbviewer/11773